# how to get array data latitude longitude in fragment?

Tags: android, arraylist, maps, fragment, latitude-longitude

pardon my english, how can I retrieve latitude data from the arraylist that I made on the data island separately, how to convert this line to data in my data array?
LatLng sydney = New LatLng (-34, 151);

MapsActivity.java

hopefully explain I can understand

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        **LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);**
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

IslandData.java

```
public class IslandData {

    public static String[][] data = new String[][] {

            {"-8.586478",
             "119.432801"},
            {"-8.712502",
             "116.995508"},
            {"-0.221392",
             "130.494268"},
            {"-2.605546",
             "140.557166"},
            {"-8.324768",
             "115.118091"},
            {"1.622413",
             "124.760006"},
            {"-4.082819",
             "137.289229"},
            {"-3.115814",
             "119.670047"},
            {"-7.608001",
             "110.203859"},
            {"-6.302454",
             "106.895116"}
    };

    public static  ArrayList<Island> getListData(){
        Island island;
        ArrayList<Island> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String[] mData : data) {
            island = new Island();
            island.setLatitude(mData[0]);
            island.setLongitude(mData[1]);

            list.add(island);

        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Island.java

```
public class Island implements Parcelable {
    private String name, elevation, photo, description, location, latitude, longitude;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getElevation() {
        return elevation;
    }

    void setElevation(String elevation) {
        this.elevation = elevation;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    Island() {
    }

    private Island(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        elevation = in.readString();
        photo = in.readString();
        description = in.readString();
        location = in.readString();
        latitude = in.readString();
        longitude = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Island> CREATOR = new Creator<Island>() {
        @Override
        public Island createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Island(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Island[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Island[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(elevation);
        parcel.writeString(photo);
        parcel.writeString(description);
        parcel.writeString(location);
        parcel.writeString(latitude);
        parcel.writeString(longitude);
    }
}
```

LatLng sydney = New LatLng (-34, 151);